# Parse PHP Array To Build SQL String

Tags: php, arrays

I am passing an array of data from a `select` like so:

```
<div style="margin:10px;">
<select name="selectlist[]" multiple style="min-width: 200px;" id="selectlist">
  <option value="userid">User ID</option>
  <option value="username">User Name</option>
</select></div>
<div><input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btnYes" onclick="Scriptit()"></div>
<div id="displaypart"></div>
<script>
function Scriptit(){
var selectlist = $('#selectlist').val();
jQuery.ajax({ 
url: "<?php echo JURI::base();?>Terminator.php",
type: 'POST',
dataType: "html",
data: { selectlist: selectlist},
success : function(result) {
 $('#displaypart').empty();
$('#displaypart').append(result);
} ,
error: function(){}});}
</script>
```

Now on my page **Terminator.php** how do I check what elements were selected (I.E. in the array) so I know how to build my query string.  Something like this (pseudocdoe not php)

```
$selectlist = implode(',',$_REQUEST['selectlist']);

$sql = "Select";
if $selectlist.contains("userid") then $sql = .$sql & a.userid;
if $selectlist.contains("username") then $sql = .$sql & b.username;

if $selectlist.contains("userid") then $sql .$sql & from useridtable a;
if $selectlist.contains("username") then $sql = .$sql & inner join usernametable b on a.usralra = b.usralra;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to implode the array and then search in a string. Just search into the array you have posted.

Get the data as $_POST['selectdata'].

Then search in array

```
if(in_array('username', $selectdata)) $sql ='';
```

Comment: Excellent advice!  What is the proper syntax to combine the multiple $sql variables I will be creating?

Comment: If you have the sting in order you can use $sql .= 'query string'

Comment: @Pratyush, I know, but that's not the question.

Comment: @SimoneCabrino Yepp. I should have tagged the asker that his code is prone to sql injection. :)